# How it possible to see the site under DDoS

Tags: networking, browser, ddos

I need to go to the site which currently under DDoS attack or Under huge load. Is it some way to do that? Maybe some specefic options in browser or some ports, or anything else?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theres various types of DDoS attacks which can happen, but your chances of accessing the site amongst them is pretty much own to dumb luck.

- Memory DDOS - This happens when the attackers are exploiting a specific flaw in the code to cache large amounts of data and run the server out of ram. The result will be lots of slow connections extending into aborted. Nothing you can do here, just wait it out.
- Network DDOS - This happens when a large amount of data comes into the network from the attackers, in this case you can sometimes visit it, patience is a virtue though. But chances are your connection will timeout before the data is sent back
- CPU DDOS - This happens when the attackers are exploiting a specific flaw in the code to process large amounts of data, sending the CPU skyrocketing. Again this is a wait it out scenario as chances are theres not enough juice left to process the requests.

**In a DDOS the best way to deal with something like this is wait it out I'm afraid, hitting a already downed website with more data is also just not polite ;)**

Comment: Think in my case it's close to Network DDoS. Think that it's just somethink like botnet or maybe some scripts send a lot of request ro server. But the server is quite poor and it looks like there are no even dummy protection from such an issue

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of DDoS is to prevent access to the site :-) So contact your network administrator so that he configures the firewall to block access to this site from all IP addresses except yours.

Comment: But it's not mine. I just need to see some content from it. And I suppouse that maybe someway exist to increas my chances to do that.

Comment: If it's not yours then you will have to contact the owner.